# c# list the sum of selected elements

Tags: c#

In c# I am writing a program for credit cards. The list I have contains id, name,  city, limit and balance each with their respective variable type.  I am trying to add up the total for all cards in a list for the balance only using a method rather than in the main code

The list is polulates like so, JD069, John Brown, Sydney, $5000, $3500. I will post the code when im on my computer next.

this is my code for the list located in the class program Main,

```
        CreditCard A = new CreditCard("AB003", "Bob Brown", "Sydney", 5000, 250);
        CreditCard B = new CreditCard("BC034", "Jack Johns", "Brisbane", 4500, 2500);
        CreditCard C = new CreditCard("DE055", "John James", "Wollongong", 2500, 300);
        CreditCard D = new CreditCard("FG405", "James Williams", "Canberra", 6000, 5600);

        List<CreditCard> Cards = new List<CreditCard>();
        Cards.Add(A);
        Cards.Add(B);
        Cards.Add(C);
        Cards.Add(D);
```

The calculation for the sum of all balances I need to put into a class program

Comment: Can you post the code you're currently trying to get to work, and/or any error you're receiving?

Comment: "only using a method rather than in the main code" What does this mean?  Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: Good for you, keep trying.  Perhaps post some code, and we'll be more able to help.

Answer (score 3):

Try this (assume that your list is called myList):

```
var sum = (from foo in myList select foo.balance).Sum();
```

Comment: Thanks ill give that try and see if it gives me what I am trying to do

Comment: I have tried this but .Sum() does not show in the light blue as it should, I am using 2010, might this cause a problem?